# How do I set up GRUB in a USB to boot into an IMG?

Tags: grub2

I have an IMG file that I'd like to copy into an empty USB and boot from it, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the usb as vfat, or if you want a persistant partition let me know and I'll add those instructions too later:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb #if the usb is listed as sdb
    d
    n
    p
    1
    <enter>
    <enter>
    t
    c
    w
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
mkdir /mnt/temp; mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/temp
mkdir /mnt/temp2; mount -o loop /path/to/the/ISO.iso
```

Copy everything over:

```
rsync -avhP /mnt/temp2/* /mnt/temp
```

Install grub:

```
grub-install --no-floppy --root-directory=/mnt/temp /dev/sdb
```

Then just make your grub.cfg. Shouldn't be too difficult. Or you just just leave it blank and boot with grub commands if you want. Each time you try to boot it though it'll take something along the lines of:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz
initrd /boot/initrd.img boot=casper cdrom-detect/try-usb=true
```

Comment: What do you mean persistent partition? I just want an `.img` file that can be modified be made bootable using GRUB. And is it not possible with any other format?